# What is the -DLINUX flag for gcc?

Tags: gcc

I have seen makefiles use the -DLINUX flag but can't find any documentation on it. 
Is there a place to find information on tools like 'gcc' that are more up-to-date than
the officially released manuals?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning it's nothing special. You might see stuff like `-DDEBUG` or `-DNDEBUG`.

Comment: Err, isn't there a manpage available?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. Trojanfoe, I made a silly mistake by not thinking -DLINUX was a customization of the simpler -D and kept searching the manual for "DLINUX." I'd like to upvote everyone's answers, but don't have enough reputations yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just defines the `LINUX` symbol for the C preprocessor.

Probably there are pieces of the code that look like:

```
#ifdef LINUX
    //Linux-specific code
#elif defined WINDOWS
    //Windows-specific code
#endif
```

Comment: Doubtful; `LINUX` must be defined (to anything) and `WINDOWS` must be defined to non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `-D` option [controlling the preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options). It defines the `LINUX` macro, that you can then use with `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man gcc`:

```
   -D name
       Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.
```

Hence, it let define a constant from the compilation command line.

Answer (score 0):

It defines a preprocessor macro named LINUX. That's it. The macro itself, LINUX, is not a predefined one, it's probably used for a cross-platform codebase where specific sections of code are enabled for a Linux target. For this purpose, one could actually have re-used the predefined `linux` or `__linux__` ones (see the output of `gcc -dP -E - < /dev/null` to get all the predefined macros on your system).

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/ for the standard documentation on gcc (that's obviously for GCC 4.8.2). To my knowledge, that's the best place to look for if this documentation is not already installed (or up-to-date) on your system.